# Best approach to using unittest with Django

Tags: python, django, python-unittest

This may seem a very general question, but I hope not. I need to write tests for a Django backend before writing the Django code and then testing it. One of the first problems I can see is that this might use a lot of resources and be extremely slow. What is the standard way to test Django code? Do people write code snippets and test them individually before incorporating them into the whole or is there a better way or better framework than unittest? Is there a Django specific testing framework?

Before you answer, I don't have much experience with Django, but I can learn if you point me to the right tutorials.

Put simply, what is the best way to test Django code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Django comes with an in-built testing module/framework which is very much useful in mocking your api/routes and also redirects as well.
[This](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/) has extensive use of Django Testcase and uses TDD model of development

Here is an example.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

from accounts.forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm


class AccountsTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.register_data = {
            'email': 'xyz@gmail.com',
            'username': 'new_user1',
            'password': 'test',
            'password_confirmation': 'test'
        }
        User.objects.create_user('test', 'test@example.com', 'test')

    def tearDown(self):
        User.objects.get(username='test').delete()

    def test_get_register(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('auth:register'))
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'accounts/register.html')
        self.assertIsInstance(response.context['form'], RegistrationForm)

    def test_get_login(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('auth:login'))
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'accounts/login.html')
        self.assertIsInstance(response.context['form'], LoginForm)

    def test_register(self):
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse('auth:register'), data=self.register_data
        )
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/auth/login/')
        # new user was created
```

Comment: So do you normally write tests before you write your code on top of the template? Is that best and most practical?

Comment: in case of TDD (test-driven developement) yes. It would be time consuming but robust and easy to maintenance. It is an architectural decision to considering trade-offs anyway.

Comment: That's wonderful thankyou - one more thing - what in your opinion is the best course to learn specifically Django test driven development - extra emphasis on the Django testing

Comment: https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/. And official Django site has extensive and great material. But most importantly, nothing is better than starting off and getting your hands dirty. Just start off and you will encounter few other challenges but you will learn.